# How can I scrape images off of a webage using Perl

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I would like to scrape all images off of a webpage and am running into a problem I don't understand.

For instance if I use enter [https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=%22escape%20room%22+movie+poster&safe=images](https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=%22escape%20room%22%20movie%20poster&safe=images) into my browser and then use the browser's "View Source" option I get a massive amount of text/code. Using "find" I get more than 400 instances of

> https://

So the simple code I wrote (below) gets the content and writes the result to a file.  But a grep search of https:// only returns 7 instances.  So obviously I am doing something incorrectly, perhaps the page is dynamic and I can't access that part?

Is there a way I can get the same source, via Perl, that I get via View Source?

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0");

my $sstring = "https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=%22escape%20room%22+movie+poster&safe=images";     

my $req = new HTTP::Request 'GET' => $sstring;
$req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');

my $res = $ua->request($req);

open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt');
print $fh $res->decoded_content;
close $fh;
```

Here's the example I got from WWW:Mechanize::Chrome

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new();
my $sstring = "https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=\"" . $arrayp . "\"" . "+movie+poster&safe=images";        
$mech->get($sstring);

sleep 5;

print $_->get_attribute('href'), "\n\t-> ", $_->get_attribute('innerHTML'), "\n"
          for $mech->selector('a.download');
```

Comment: @toolic But it's still not the 400+ so something is different

Answer (score 4):

The Google search uses `Javascript` to alter the page content after load. `LWP::UserAgent` does not support `Javascript` and what you get is only the initial document. (Hint: An easy way to see in the browser what `LWP::UserAgent` "sees" is using a browser addon to disable `Javascript`).

You will need to use something that is called a "headless Browser", for example [WWW::Mechanize::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome)

Comment: Thanks, but when I run an example (added to bottom of OP) I get an _italic_ error when connectingInternal Exception at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/WWW/Mechanize/Chrome.pm line 1000 _italic_ error.  Which comes up with nothing at Google and is beyond my capabilities to debug.  Do you know of any alternative to WWW::Mechanize::Chrome?

Comment: `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. Duh. Head over to PerlMonks.org The author of both the modules, Corion, is quite active there.